# terraform error - Unknown Filter Key: MSRC_SEVERITY

Tags: terraform

Error message

````
    aws_ssm_patch_baseline.baseline: Modifying... [id=pb-041e9a4a9c8723c10]
    ╷
    │ Error: error updating SSM Patch Baseline (pb-041e9a4a9c8723c10): ValidationException: Unknown Filter Key: MSRC_SEVERITY
    │       status code: 400, request id: b55aa4df-b782-4e40-a3a7-5637ac903bdd
    │
    │   with aws_ssm_patch_baseline.baseline,
    │   on ssm.tf line 1, in resource "aws_ssm_patch_baseline" "baseline":
    │    1: resource "aws_ssm_patch_baseline" "baseline" {```
````

Terraform file content

```
    patch_filter {
          key    = "MSRC_SEVERITY"
          values = var.patch_severity
        }
```

Operating system for patch baseline is AMAZON_LINUX

For console, similar choice is available for selection in drop down field
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different operating systems support different filter properties. Unfortunately AWS doesn't seem to tell you exactly which operating systems support which properties but [the API docs list the valid values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_PatchFilter.html) of properties and then you can run the following command to check whether they are valid for that operating system and what options are available:

```sh
$ aws ssm describe-patch-properties --operating-system AMAZON_LINUX --property MSRC_SEVERITY

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DescribePatchProperties operation: Property MSRC_SEVERITY is not supported for operating system AMAZON_LINUX

$ aws ssm describe-patch-properties --operating-system AMAZON_LINUX --property SEVERITY
{
    "Properties": [
        {
            "Name": "Critical"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Important"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Low"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Medium"
        }
    ]
}
```

For reference, [MSRC is the Microsoft Security Response Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/msrc?rtc=1) so it makes sense that this only applies to Windows systems.